# trying to use vedio clip as wordpress preloader but not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, preloader

my client ask me to run a vedio as preloader. I have tried many tricks but not working properly.

I have tried many tricks but not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in functions.php

```
<?php

function add_video_preloader() {
?>
    <div id="preloader">
        <video id="preloader-video" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/{your-video-file-name.mp4}" autoplay muted loop></video>
    </div>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_video_preloader' );
?>
```

And add below code in theme's style.css

```
#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#preloader-video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```